# I want to block window.location.href in a new tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect

I have a link that opens in a new tab, in the new tab's header it has javascript like this which redirects it to a different page:

```
window.location.href = "{a different URL}";
```

I need to debug the new tab before it redirects in an incognito window. What can I do in chrome to stop the new tab from redirecting so that I can debug it? I can't take the redirect out because I need to debug it in a live environment to replicate an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint for `beforeunload` in the source panel of the Chrome debugger:

[image: Chrome debugger beforeunload event breakpoint location]

This will fire when `window.location` changes

Comment: How do you set the breakpoint in that page if it redirects before you can stop it?

Comment: you set the breakpoint in chrome. It will stop on every `beforeunload` event. So resume execution for the first navigation and then it will pause again for the redirect

Comment: I don't understand, I open devtools in the first page, set the breakpoint, click on the link that opens the new tab. The new tab opens with devtools open but without the breakpoint, then redirects before I can do anything.

Comment: can you open it in the same tab?

Comment: oh yeah i guess i could just remove that in the HTML!